# Apache JKmanager Activation Status is not updating

Tags: apache

I have changed the Activation Status of JKManager node1 from Activate to Deactivate and once after access the application URL and login the status of the JKManager gets changed to activate status.And i couldn't find any errors in Apache logs.Does is there  any other configuration required?

My application is using  Server Version: Apache/2.2.15 (Win32) mod_jk/1.2.265,mod-jk and Jboss Application Server Version 6.And below is the configured worker.properties file

```
worker.list=workerlist
# Set properties for node1
worker.node1.type=ajp13
worker.node1.host=xxxx
worker.node1.port=xx
worker.node1.lbfactor=4


# Set properties for node2
worker.node2.type=ajp13
worker.node2.host=xxxx
worker.node2.port=xx
worker.node2.lbfactor=4


# Set properties for workerlist(lb)
worker.workerlist.type=lb
worker.workerlist.balance_workers=node1,node2
worker.workerlist.sticky_session=1

worker.list=jkstatus
worker.jkstatus.type=status
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to Jboss Application server(Server.xml) and Apache Server(V_host) are configured with same port and we have changed the Port of JBOSS in server.xml which resolved the issue.Thanks